# Localhost tcp throughput performance differences

Tags: windows, performance, tcp, localhost, performance-tuning

I have been using [psping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx) for measuring bandwith statistics on localhost on different computers: **laptops, home computers and servers**. All of them get to between **100** and **200** **MB/s** but my PowerPc at work manages to get to **800 MB/s**.

What can cause these huge differences communicating with itself over localhost? The PowerPc outperforms all other devices I've tested **with a factor 4 to 8**.

**PowerPc configuration**

- Windows 7
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1240 v3 @ 3.40GHz [Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3]
- [3.78 GFLOPS/core](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/cpu_list.php)
- Symantec SEP

**A Home computer configuration**

- Windows 8.1
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67GHz [Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5]   4
- [2.64 GFLOPS/core](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/cpu_list.php)
- BitDefender

**psping command**

```
psping -4 -b -l 8k -n 20000 localhost:1234
```

#### A few questions I expect to get and like to address up front

*I might be way off but this shows you my current understanding of things, feel free to set me straight.*

1. Antivirus related
   I have turned of the antivirus component om my Home Computer without any noticable difference. Further, I have captured a WPA trace [*(XperfScripts)*](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dae128bd454cf957&id=DAE128BD454CF957%217152&ithint=folder,zip&authkey=!ALq3LqMcfgs8JoM) and the modules that have most CPU related activity are ntoskrnl.exe, netio.sys, tcpip.sys, ndis.sys and afd.sys. The first AV module that comes into the picture CPU related is avcuf32.dll accounting for 0.17% of total CPU.
2. Localhost vs. 127.0.0.1
   I have tried both and got the same results on all tested computers.
3. Up-to-date drivers
   The drivers on my Home computer are up-to-date. The drivers on the PowerPc are managed by our IT staff and lag behind somewhat but not that much *(and the PowerPc is 4x faster on the tests anyway)*
4. netsh int tcp show global
   There are some differences between both PC's. *Chimney Offload State* and *NetDMA State* on my Home Computer are disabled while on the PowerPc they are automatic and enabled.
   My networking-fu is not good enough to know if that could explain for the differences but reading up on the subject, I doubt it is.

---

**Edit**

RAM details PowerPC

```
  capacity speed memorytype totalwidth datawidth typedetail
  -------- ----- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
4294967296  1600          0         64        64        128
4294967296  1600          0         64        64        128
4294967296  1600          0         64        64        128
4294967296  1600          0         64        64        128
```

RAM details Home computer

```
    capacity speed memorytype totalwidth datawidth typedetail
  -------- ----- ---------- ---------- --------- ----------
2147483648  1333          1         72        64          2
4294967296  1333          1         72        64          2
2147483648  1333          1         72        64          2
4294967296  1333          1         72        64          2
2147483648  1333          1         72        64          2
4294967296  1333          1         72        64          2
   4194304    33         11          8         8       4096
```

Comment: first, confirm that your B's are all the same case (MB/Mb), since 800Mb == 100MB.

Comment: sorry, fat fingered enter, and had to edit to complete the comment. usually the thing that really speeds up LAN file operations is RAID and the way disks collaborate (or don't) when performing IO. for instance you will never get more than 35MB/s when the source or destination of a piece of data is connected over usb2. That in and of itself is the reason that my work PC has more network capacity than my home, since the servers are all RAID5, despite the fact that my home network is faster.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I see <g>. All B's are the same case. I think you misinterpreted my question. There's no disk or usb involved. psping is merely a network testing tool and for this case, I am testing how fast the computer can communicate with itself over localhost *(in the end to solve an ipc over tcp issue we have with an application)*

Comment: Put NIC details and RAM details.

Comment: @ali786 - All traffic is from/to localhost. The physical NIC doesn't play a part *(tcpip.sys is the lowest in the stack the traffic goes)*. I have added RAM details to the question. I'll add those from my Home computer when I'm, well, home <g>.

Comment: How much RAM total for each computer? The main difference in speed is supposed to be the memory speed, as frames are copied among TCP layers. Windows 8 is supposed to be much faster because of [Fast TCP Loopback](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path.aspx), unless PsPing does not use it. You should ping using blocks of 8960 bytes to use [Jumbo frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame) for a very minor improvement.

Comment: Also: All conditions should be the same : `netsh int tcp set global chimney=automatic` and `netsh int tcp set global netdma=enabled`. NetDMA can have an effect, since it allows network adapters to transfer data directly to your application without needing your CPU, perhaps this way reducing memory copies.

Comment: @harrymc - Setting chimney to automatic improved a bit but not much. Setting netdma enabled doesn't seem to "stick". I get an ok from netsh when exeucting the command but when showing the global settings, it's still set to disabled.

Comment: Try this for enabling NetDMA: regedit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` and create a new DWORD item named `EnableTCPA` with value 1. Reboot might be required. How much RAM in GB for each computer?

Comment: Setting it right now and preparing for reboot. While rebooting -> I am comparing two WPA traces right now and everything seems to indicate a CPU issue *(what I actually kind of dismissed from the beginning and still find hard to believe)*. Both traces account for 400K context switches, both traces have for the duration of the test used 20% CPU but one only needs 3.6 seconds and the other needs 14.1 seconds.

Comment: *(16GB and 18GB of RAM. I have added it to the question)* Setting EnableTCPA and rebooting didn't help. The setting is still disabled. Can you perhaps perform the same bandwith test and share your results? I have tried on different systems and all get between 100 and 200MB/s, only the PowerPc get's as high as 800MB/s.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers ,Tcpip.sys is a Windows driver & has direct access to the internals of the operating system, hardware etc. we use 127.0.0.1 to test whether NIC is working or not, your NIC configuration may be different.

Comment: @ali786 - It is perfectly possible to ping localhost on a computer without a NIC at all, it's all software. I don't understand what data you want me to provide? Do you have a command, like ipconfig in mind?

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 my speeds are 200-300 MB. This is better than yours, but I used a high-powered PC, so maybe memory copies were faster and memory is indeed the main factor of performance. I also do not manage to set NetDMA, and the reason is because of missing IPMONTR.DLL. For the moment I favor NetDMA as the reason for the performance differences. Questions: (1) Do you have IPMONTR.DLL on the PowerPC, and if so I would like to have a copy for more testing (it's in `C:\Windows\System32`), (2) I suppose the PowerPC has Windows 7 x64?

Comment: @harrymc - Yes, windows 7 x64. Thank you for trying. Funny enough, I don't have `ipmontr.dll` on my system. Just did a `dir c:\ipmontr.dll /s` after not seeing it under system32 but the search comes up blank. I did a `netsh int tcp show global` again to make sure NetDMA is enabled. It is. Where did you find the reference to ipmontr.dll?

Comment: I have done `netsh int tcp set global netdma` and gotten an error message about that dll. The funny thing is that now `show global` shows NetDMA as enabled and repeating the test now gives the speed of 500 MB !!! I think that this points conclusively to NetDMA as the reason for the difference; and also that Microsoft has serious bugs in the implementation of its user interface.

Comment: So enabling NetDMA increases the speed by a factor two. Time to read up on NetDMA I guess. If you happen to find something else, please share. If you post your findings as an answer, I'll accept later on. Thank you Harry, happy new year.

Comment: The weirdness continues: After reboot, NetDMA is still shown as enabled, but throughput is now down to 200 MB. Possibly Microsoft has some serious bugs in its NetDMA implementation, but conjunctures are useless. Be happy that it works on the PowerPC. If nobody from Microsoft volunteers here a better explanation, I will post this as an answer in a couple of days.

Comment: I've pinged Mark Russinovich about it and he gave some pointers but he doesn't have time to look into it. From the WPA traces I've taken, I'm inclined to say it's a scheduling problem. PsPing spends 225M µs in Wait on the slow machine and 50M µs in wait on the machine while the CPU is on neither machine doing much (if anything). The slow machine started 11 threads and the fast started 33. According to Mark, PsPing starts threads depending on CPU's but the slow one got 12CPU's and the fast one only 8. It' puzzling to say the least.

Comment: What were the pointers?

Comment: To take a WPA trace *(which I actually already did but failed to mention in the mail)* and the thread/CPU fact *(which was after all a puzzle in by itself)*

Comment: As PsPing starts a random number of threads, it's unsuitable for comparison. Using the [PCATTCP](http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/pcattcp.htm) tool I found on google, I got wildly different results on each run : 268,431,297,380MB. Conclusion: Microsoft loopback implementation is so lousy that in Windows 8/2012 they [rewrote it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path.aspx). The numbers are not to be trusted. I still must figure out how to stop netsh complaining about missing IPMONTR.DLL.

Comment: Note: For anyone else who googled the netsh message "helper DLL cannot be loaded: IPMONTR.DLL" and happened upon this discussion : The solution is to run the command `netsh delete helper IPMONTR.DLL`.

Comment: @harrymc - PsPing does give consistent results per machine but you might be right about it being unsuitable for comparision, hard to tell. I also found that fast loopback article but it requires changes to client the software too. That is not under our control unfortenately. Definitely going to try the delete command and post back te results once I get home (in about 10 hours).

Comment: It would be interesting to try again using PCATTCP on both computers, doing several runs and taking their average. It's a great mystery how NetDMA got enabled and is really working on the PowerPC.

Comment: Using `pcattcp -t localhost`On the PowerPc, I got following results (KB/s): *(average 556738)* 862315,780190,606814,512000,481882,364088,496484,496484,564965,682666,512000,655360,442810,546133,512000,481882,606814,431157,630153,455111,780190. I'll try at home when at home.

Comment: Using 200000 calls, it evens out at about 680MB/s `pcattcp -t -n200000 localhost`.

Comment: The Home Computer gets to 200MB/s with 200.000 calls. IPMONTR.DLL is not defined as a helper on the system.

Comment: I think I may have found it. The Microsoft article [Enabling NetDMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg162687%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) has this: "NetDMA must be enabled in the BIOS before performing this procedure. NetDMA support is often labeled IOAT support." This might explain these differences, if the BIOS on the PowerPC supports it, but not on the Windows 8.1 computer (or support is disabled in the BIOS or UEFI). This might explain why Windows sets it to On on the PowerPC and why it is always Off on the other computer no matter what you do to enable it.

Comment: Do you see any such option in the BIOS (or UEFI?) on your home computer?

Comment: More: The Microsoft article [NetDMA (Windows Drivers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says : "The NetDMA interface is not supported in Windows 8 and later". So this is why Microsoft needed to add the Fast TCP Loopback, but unfortunately it's not backward-compatible with existing applications. I will compose an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Harrymc - No option in my bios for IOAT support. I've played around with HPET to see if that makes a difference but it only got slower. Thanks for your time and answer Harry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the reason that the PowerPC on Windows 7 is much faster on localhost
loopback throughput, is because it can use NetDMA.

The Microsoft article [NetDMA (Windows Drivers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) defines NetDMA as :

> The NetDMA interface provides a generic interface for memory-to-memory
>   direct memory access (DMA) transfers. Although the interface is
>   designed to copy packets that are received from high-performance
>   network interface cards (NICs), you can also use the interface for
>   other applications. There is no direct relationship between NetDMA and
>   NDIS.

When using localhost loopback, it stands to reason that
memory copy operations are the main factor of throughput,
as frames are copied from the source-application memory, then between TCP layers
and finally to the memory of the target-application.

NetDMA can have an impact, since it allows network adapters to transfer data directly to your application, perhaps this way reducing the number of memory copies
even for the trivial loopback adapter.

Enabling NetDMA can be done in two ways :

1. Enter `netsh int tcp set global netdma=enabled` in Command Prompt (cmd)
   that is run as Administrator, then reboot.
2. Regedit to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` and create a new DWORD item named `EnableTCPA` with the value 1, then reboot.

However, there are two prerequisites to enabling NetDMA :

1. The Microsoft article [Enabling NetDMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg162687%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) has this :

> NetDMA must be enabled in the BIOS before performing this procedure.
>   NetDMA support is often labeled IOAT support.

2. The Microsoft article [NetDMA (Windows Drivers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has this note :

> The NetDMA interface is not supported in Windows 8 and later.

Putting both these requirements together, I can hazard the guess that,
as NetDMA is a BIOS function, it was not implemented in [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) which is
used in Windows 8/2012.

Microsoft had therefore to improve localhost loopback
throughput in another way, especially for using in
Hyper-V, and had therefore created in Windows 8/2012 the [Fast TCP Loopback](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/12/05/fast-tcp-loopback-performance-and-low-latency-with-windows-server-2012-tcp-loopback-fast-path.aspx),
defined as :

> TCP Loopback Fast Path is a new feature introduced in Windows Server
>   2012 and Windows 8. If you use the TCP loopback interface for
>   inter-process communications (IPC), you may be interested in the
>   improved performance, improved predictability, and reduced latency the
>   TCP Loopback Fast Path can provide.  This feature preserves TCP socket
>   semantics and platform capabilities including the Windows Filtering
>   Platform (WFP), and works on both non-virtualized and virtualized
>   operating system instances.
>
> The TCP loopback interface provides a simple local IPC mechanism for
>   processes on the same operating system instance, and it can easily be
>   switched to a remote IPC mechanism by simply changing the destination
>   IP address.

Unfortunately, Fast TCP Loopback is not transparent, requiring applications to
issue a WSAIoctl system call on the sockets for both sender and receiver,
therefore not being backward-compatible with existing bandwidth-measuring applications
such as [PsPing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx) and [PCATTCP](http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/pcattcp.htm).

In my own tests on Windows 7, I have not fathomed all the mysteries surrounding NetDMA,
but I have managed to briefly turn it on, with the immediate benefit of doubling
my bandwidth as measured by PsPing. But as NetDMA did not survive a reboot
on that computer,
I do not recommend depending on it for throughput even
on computers that theoretically support it.

Comment: I have WPA traces of both a fast and slow system. Do you happen to have any experience in interpreting such traces? Every time I start slicing and dicing them, I find myself concluding other things, depending on what I started grouping on.

Comment: *(Love the way how you've put this together btw)*

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience with WPA traces, but I can see that there is a lot of material on the Web. You could maybe try to find out and target the interesting EventSources rather than everything.